# the unexpected spaces between the rows and the columns in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width/3), height: collectionView.frame.size.height/2)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.item)
    }
}
```

The numbers are all zero but there are still spaces between each row and column. And, the space between the rows is bigger than that between the columns. For more information, I put constraints of leading, trailing, top and bottom on the collection view. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Did you set the view controller to be the collection view's delegate? So are those functions actually called?

Comment: I already added the following codes in the viewDidLoad. collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

Comment: I cannot repeat your issue. Good luck.